# Objects not affected by gravity field in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit for a 3d physics simulation of dice.  I'm trying to have only specific dice be affected using SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField().  I have all the necessary code in place I think, but it's just not working.  The physics bodies aren't effected by the gravity field, even though it's infinite by default, and they're in the same category.  I'm using swift.

```
let downGravityCatagory = 1 << 0
let fieldDown = SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField()
let fieldUp = SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField()
let fieldNode = SCNNode()

let sceneView = view as! SCNView
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

fieldDown.categoryBitMask = downGravityCatagory
fieldDown.active = true
fieldDown.strength = 3
fieldNode.physicsField = fieldDown
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(fieldNode)

var dice = SCNNode()
//I then attach geometry here
dice.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: dice.geometry!, options: nil))
dice.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = downGravityCatagory
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(dice)
```

This problem is the bane of my existence.  As far as I can tell this is how the code should be written.  All prerequisites required for this to work have been met as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, the duplicate question doesn't (yet) have an answer, but asking almost exactly the same question twice in fifteen hours is not the way to get answers. Try editing your original to discuss more attempts you've taken to diagnose the problem. Or just be patient — [tag:scenekit] isn't a super-high-traffic tag and I don't think it's full of people for whom posting to SO is their actual job, so it might take a little while for the community to dig into your problem enough to find a  solution.

Comment: Ah but it increases my chances mathematically.  Just as buying two lottery tickets increases my chances of winning the lottery.  Ha!  Just kidding it's quite shameful.